# MySQL conditional text aggregation

Tags: mysql, database-design, aggregate

I currently have the following model for input:

```
+---------+-----------+---------+---------+--------+
| user_id |   date    | program |  type   |  more  |
+---------+-----------+---------+---------+--------+
|       1 | 23-Mar-15 | AAA     | init    |        |
|       1 | 21-May-15 | AAA     | 1/3     |        |
|       1 | 22-Sep-15 | AAA     | 1/3     |        |
|       1 | 20-Mar-16 | AAA     | 1/3     |        |
|       1 | 12-Aug-16 | CCC     | init    |        |
|       1 | 27-Jun-18 | CCC     | init    | refund |
|       2 | 16-May-16 | BBB     | init    |        |
|       2 | 12-Aug-16 | BBB     | full    |        |
|       2 | 15-Mar-17 | AAA     | 1/3     |        |
|       2 | 21-Jun-17 | AAA     | 1/3     | refund |
|       3 | 24-May-18 | BBB     | init    |        |
|       3 | 27-May-18 | BBB     | 1/3     |        |
|       3 | 27-Jun-18 | BBB     | 2/3     |        |
|       4 | 27-Jun-18 | AAA     | init    |        |
|       5 | 27-Jun-18 | AAA     | 1/3     |        |
|       5 | 27-Jun-18 | AAA     | 1/3     |        |
+---------+-----------+---------+---------+--------+
```

Result im looking for is:

```
+---------+----------+------------+
| user_id | programs | aggregated |
+---------+----------+------------+
|       1 | AAA      | full       |
|       1 | CCC      | refund     |
|       2 | BBB      | full       |
|       2 | AAA      | refund     |
|       3 | BBB      | 2/3        |
|       4 | AAA      | init       |
|       5 | AAA      | 2/3        |
+---------+----------+------------+
```

I am looking for advise on how to design the input table to be able to get requested result. In previous iterations I had tens of different options for every program, but I found that approach completely useless. So I have significantly simplified possible program types. But still I dont see how I could aggregate the data using this input. If I am too stupid to see that its already possible to get the result I'm looking for from existing input, please point me to direction.

Question TL:DR
 - is aggregation im looking for possible/viable using my current input table in MySQL?
 - if not, what kind of modification would you advise to my input table?
 - if yes, kindly please point me in right direction.

**EDIT**

Attempt to describe logic in more detail:

every user can have multiple programs

every program can be acquired by user in parts that are represented in type column.

program AAA has only following inputs options init, 1/2, 1/3, or full possible in that row  (i have no influence over that).

other programs have: 1/2, 2/2, 1/3, 2/3, 3/3, full, init

every program can have one of following states types as a **result**: init, 1/2, 
 1/3, 2/3, full, refund

Pseudo code:

```
For every program that user has:
 If there is only one type for a program then result = that type.   
 If there is more than one type of program: 
   check if there are any refund    
    if every program type has refund, then result = refund  
    if there are program type without refund, result = aggregated   
    if there are no refunds, then result = aggregated
```

Comment: how do you determine the aggreate result? The logic behind it?

Comment: please give me couple minutes I'll try to describe it in more detail

Comment: I don't see where that result is coming from. None of the rows with `1 AAA` or `2 BBB` have `full` in them.

Comment: I have added some more details I hope it makes it a bit more clear. Thank you for helping.

Comment: @Barmar full in result shows when user has all parts of a program, for example if user has three rows with program AAA and type 1/3 result should be 1 | AAA | full

Comment: @KristjanKica added i hope better explanation

Comment: Last two cases seem to be the same, they both have result = aggregated.

Comment: Why is it `1 CCC refund`? There's only one type for `1 CCC`, so result = that type, which is `init`.

Comment: `5 AAA` only has one type = `1/3`, so result = that type. But you have `5 AAA 2/3` in your desired result. Why isn't it `5 AAA 1/3`?

Comment: 1 CCC refund, because in input there was 1 CCC init and 1 CCC refund, so they cancel out (if every program type has refund, then result = refund)
5 AAA has type = 1/3 in two rows, so result should be 5 AAA 2/3

Comment: Where does the question say anything about types cancelling each other out?

Comment: **If there is only one type for a program then result = that type.** That doesn't match `type = 1/3 in two rows` means `result = 2/3`.

Comment: I am sorry I thought that: 'if every program type has refund, then result = refund' was referring to that case. What I meant there is when user has rows with same program type and refund in more column, then result should be refund - so like canceling out: 1 CCC init  1 CCC init refund, should produce refund.

Comment: If there is only one type for a program then result = that type.

I am sorry again i sit working on this 20h straight, my brain is not working properly. It should say 'if user has only one row for program type, than result = that type - i'll edit post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT user_id, program,
    CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT type) = 1 THEN MAX(type) -- one type, use that type
        WHEN SUM(more = 'refund') = COUNT(DISTINCT type) THEN 'refund'
        WHEN SUM(IF(LOCATE('/', type), SUBSTRING_INDEX(type, '/', 1), 0)) >= 3 THEN 'full'
        WHEN MAX(LOCATE('/', type)) > 0 THEN CONCAT(SUM(IF(LOCATE('/', type), SUBSTRING_INDEX(type, '/', 1), 0)), '/3')
        ELSE MAX(type)
    AS aggregated
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY user_id, program
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6a6c/3)

Comment: wow thank you! Let me try to run it. I seem to understand all other options, but can you explain what this line does:

WHEN MAX(LOCATE('/', type)) > 0 THEN CONCAT(SUM(IF(LOCATE('/', type), SUBSTRING_INDEX(type, '/', 1), 0)), '/3')

Comment: If any of the types have `/` in them, it adds together the parts before `/` and then puts `/3` after that sum.

Comment: This isn't producing the same as your desired results, but it seems like your description of all the cases doesn't match the results. See my comments above.

Comment: I have replied above. I think I have to have separate logic for aggregating AAA program and others, is nesting CASE and option here?

Comment: If the rules for AAA are different from others, that may be the best way.